# alignment of flex box within row

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I am trying to produce a row of data like the below but I am having troubles getting my description under my title

[image]

the code I am using is

View

```
<View style={styles.row}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.namePart}>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.description}>{this.props.data.description}</Text>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.pricePart}>{this.props.data.price}</Text>
        </View>
```

styles

```
row:{
    height:rowheight,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 16,
    borderRadius:0,
    borderWidth:0,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderColor:Colors.border,
    margin:0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  namePart:{
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex:4,
  },
  pricePart:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
  },
  cartPart:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
  },
```

this is currently rendering the below
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a `<View>` with the name and description with `flexDirection: 'column'`, and this block should be inside a `<View>` with `flexDirection: 'row'`.

Something like:

View:

```
<View style={styles.row}>
  <View style={styles.column}>
    <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.namePart}>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
    <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.description}>{this.props.data.description}</Text>
  </View>
  <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.pricePart}>{this.props.data.price}</Text>
</View>
```

Style:

```
row: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
},
column: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  flex: 4,
},
pricePart: {
  flex: 1,
}
```

And you should remove all about flex from the `styles.namePart`

Comment: awesome work. Why didn't I think of this earlier, tried everything else, still trying to grasp the concept behind flex